# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, testing, import, python-unittest

I have a project arranged like so:

```
Project
└── test
    ├── main.py
    │  
    └── x.py
    │  
    └── y.py
```

I try to run the tests by executing `python -m test.main.py` from the project directory, but I get an error that says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named x`.

`main.py` contains:

```
from x import c, k
import y
```

Why do I get this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are x and y the actual names or standin names?  make sure the names of the files don't collide with any other packages installed or in the standlib.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Use *relative import*, as explained in the linked duplicates. In short, `from .x import c, k`, and `from . import y`. Since you are running the code from a parent of the `test` folder, it will all be seen as in an appropriate package, allowing these to work. The error occurs because `from x import c, k` and `import y` ask for *absolute* imports, which will check a list of specific places for the modules - and your `test` folder isn't on that list.

Comment: As an aside, the command `python -m test.main.py` is definitely a typo. When using the `-m` flag, specify a **qualified module name, not** a source file name (i.e., do not include `.py` at the end - this command would mean to look in a sub-package folder named `main`, for a file called `py.py` representing the `py` module). For the folder structure that you show, you should instead run `python -m test.main`.